# how to retrieve unknown sub collection from document in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code with the objective of retring all the documents like this: `Collection('A').document(currentUser)`, this should give me the document YRZ1**** as you may see in the first image. Now what I want to do is get all the documents in the t22o9*** subcollection, as showned on the second image, how can I do that?

```
var docPath=Firestore.instance.document('Messages/$currentUser');

docPath.snapshots().listen((event) {
  print('Hello  12 ${event.data}');

});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get data from subcollection you can do the following:

```
var db = Firestore.instance;
//This is a reference to the YRZ1**** doc
var messagesDoc = db.collection('Messages').document('Messages/$currentUser');
//collectionId is the t22o9*** id, you need to have this set previosly in your code
var docList = [];
messagesDoc.collection(collectionId)
           .getDocuments()
           .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
               snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) => docList.add(doc)'));
           });
```

With this code, `docList` will be a list of the documents located at your subcollection t22o9*** of the YRZ1*** document.

Also you can check this [link](https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27) with some examples on how to get data from firestore using flutter.

**EDIT**:

As per what you have clarified on the comments, getting the subcollection data is a bit more complicated with subcollections that were created dynamically, as you can see on this [link](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166), which I assume is the case you have. The most feasible solution in your case would be to create a list of ids of subcollections in your parent document, so for example your YRZ1*** document would have this structure

```
document
   id: YRZ1***
   subCollectionIds : [subCollectionId1, subCollectionId2,...]
   subCollection1
   subCollection2
   ...
   subCollectionN
```

Having this structure you could use this code to retrieve the list of subcollections and the first document of each subcollection, ordered by whatever field you'd like:

```
var db = Firestore.instance;
var listFirstDocSub = []
//This is a reference to the YRZ1**** doc
db.collection('Messages')
  .document('Messages/$currentUser')
  .getDocument()
  .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var listSubCollections = doc["subCollectionIds"];
      listSubCollections.forEach((id) {
          db.collection('Messages')
            .document('Messages/$currentUser')
            .collection(id)
            .orderBy("WHATEVER_FIELD_YOU_DECIDE")
            .limit(1)
            .getDocuments()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                listFirstDocSub.add(snapshot);
            }) 
      });
});
```

**NOTE**: With this approach, everytime you add a new subcollection, you will also need to add it's id to the subCollectionIds list.

Hope This helps.

Comment: thank you for your response ,but the thing is that How would i know which one is subcollection because It could t22o9*** or any other ...It might be number of SubCollectionId's..I hope you got my point

Comment: ok, so you want to list all subcollections? do you also want to get all the documents for each subcollection, or a specific one, afterwards?

Comment: Yes Exactly I want to list all subcollections. and for each subcollection i want to retrieve a single document from the list of Documents. this single document would be retrieve by orderBy() method from the listed documents

Comment: What you described is a bit more complex, so I edited the answer to reflect what you want to achieve. Let me know if this solves you issue, and if it does, remember to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: thank you soo mr.ralemos ..Your Answer was helpful .I just changed the collection with user Names and Add list of Users in same collection as document field.

Comment: Awesome, glad to know I've helped :)

Comment: I appreciate your help